# angular 7 writing test for routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have made an application with some components and I made the navigation between the pages, they work fine. I want to write a test for my routing section.

this is my `router.spec.ts`

```js
    import { Location } from "@angular/common";
    import { TestBed, fakeAsync, tick, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
    import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
    import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';
    //import { routes } from './splash-routing.module';
    
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      let location: Location;
      let router: Router;
      let fixture;
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [HomeComponent, AboutComponent, AppComponent],
          imports: [RouterTestingModule]
        }).compileComponents();
        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        location = TestBed.get(Location);
    
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        router.initialNavigation();
      }));
    
      it('should create the app', async(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        console.log(fixture);
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
      }));
    
      it('navigate to "home" redirects you to /home', fakeAsync(() => { 
        router.navigate(['home']); 
        tick(); 
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/home'); 
      }));
    
      // it('navigate to "about" takes you to /about', fakeAsync(() => {
      //   router.navigate(['about']);
      //   tick();
      //   expect(location.path()).toBe('/about');
      // }));
    });
```

my **splash-routing.module.ts**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { RootComponent } from './root/root.component';
    
    import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
    import { PricingComponent } from './pricing/pricing.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    
    
    export const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
        {path: 'pricing', component: PricingComponent},
        {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        {path: 'notfound', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
        { 
          path: '**', // bonus: all routes not defined forward to /home
          redirectTo: 'notfound'
        },
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'home'},
      ]},
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class SplashRoutingModule { }
```

when I run my tests using `ng test` I get the following error how can I fix it and what is casing this error:

[image]

can some explain to me what am I doing wrong, because i need to write test for other components here as well!

Comment: You're not specifying any routes on the RouterTestingModule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `routes` for `RouterTestingModule` using the method `withRoutes`.

Currently, you don't specify any routes and that's the reason you get an error that `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment home`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent, AboutComponent, AppComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)] <---------- 
    }).compileComponents();
```

Comment: I got a new error: Failed: Component RootComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
also Failed: Component RootComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
 and TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined!!

Comment: Sure, your base route `''` corresponds to the `RootComponent`. So either you specify `RootComponent` in declarations or you specify only the needed routes.

Comment: I am not sure why, I though i folllowd the tutorial coprrectly now I am getting two errors, AppComponent should create the app and AppComponent navigate to "home" redirects you to /home!! not quite sure, I can belive I am off so much!!